# Jasmine not loading module because of ES6 syntax?

Tags: javascript, angularjs, jasmine

I have an Angular module and I used some ES6 syntax (`=>` functions and computed key names).

It turns out Jasmine refuses to load the module and I can't test it. I'm completely sure the ES6 syntax is the reason because as soon as I change the code to ES3 syntax, Jasmine loads my module and I'm able to test it.

Why is that happening and is there a way I can tell Jasmine to load my ES6 code?

Answer (score 0):

You can use babel to transpile your es6, here's a link to how to set it up in your jasmine conf.

https://babeljs.io/docs/setup/#jasmine

Comment: Yes, thank you. My question doesn't ask that. My question is <b>can I tell Jasmine to load my ES6 code?</b>

Answer (score -1):

Jasmine is committed to supporting browsers as well as Node; they run their tests against stable browser builds. Until ES6 is fully supported in major browsers, I don't think Jasmine will be able to load your ES6 code. [From the contributing guide:](https://github.com/jasmine/jasmine/blob/master/CONTRIBUTING.md#how-to-write-new-jasmine-code)

> How to write new Jasmine code
>
> Or, How to make a successful pull request
>
> - Do not change the public interface. Lots of projects depend on Jasmine and if you aren't careful you'll break them
> - Be environment agnostic - server-side developers are just as important as browser developers
> - Be browser agnostic - if you must rely on browser-specific functionality, please write it in a way that degrades gracefully

Comment: ES6 is already supported by all browsers and node. Are you sure this can't be done?